# \$e^{i2\pi Nf_snT}=1\$ why?

Tags: signal, sampling

Why is:

\$e^{i2\pi Nf_snT}=1\$

in

[snippet from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvzZ7.png)

Comment: f_s is the sampling frequency, right?

Comment: yes f_s is the sampling frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem, f<sub>s</sub>=1/2T=1/N. Substituting into the exponential, you obtain \$e^{i2\pi nT}\$, which is equal to 1 by the Euler's identity.

Comment: so the euler's states that: \$e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)\$. Therefore, in this case, \$e^{i2\pi nT} = cos(2\pi nT) + isin(2\pi nT)\$ where sin -> 0 and cos ->1. and that's why \$e^{i2\pi nT} = 1\$, am I right?

Comment: @TheProgrammer exactly. Perhaps I should have written it more clearly.